# Spring batch RepositoryItemWriter not working

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-batch, spring-repositories, java-17

I have a scenario where a given json file **Employee.json** needs to be read to  **Employee** object and then written to **employee** table in mysql database in a batch process.

**Employee.json:**

```
    [
      {
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName":"Snow",
        "age":30
      },
      {
        "firstName": "Tony",
        "lastName": "Stark",
        "age": 40
      },
      {
        "firstName": "Peter",
        "lastName":"Parker",
        "age":35
      }
    ]
```

**Employee.java :**

```
import lombok.Data;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Data
@Entity
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int age;
}
```

I used the **JsonItemReader** for reading the file from my resource location and **RepositoryItemWriter** for persisting the employee object.

This is how my batch config looks:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "za.co.sanlam.employee")
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DataInsertJsontoMysqlJob {
    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager;

    @Autowired
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory;

    @Value("input/Employee.json")
    private Resource inputjson;

    @Bean(name = "insertDataJob")
    public Job job(@Qualifier("step1") Step step1) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("insertDataJob").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).start(step1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    protected Step step1(ItemWriter writer) throws ParseException {

        return stepBuilderFactory
                .get("step1")
                .transactionManager(platformTransactionManager)
                .<Employee, Employee>chunk(2)
                .reader(jsonItemReader())
                .writer(writer)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JsonItemReader<Employee> jsonItemReader() {
        return new JsonItemReaderBuilder<Employee>()
                .jsonObjectReader(new JacksonJsonObjectReader<>(Employee.class))
                .resource(inputjson)
                .name("jsonItemReader")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public RepositoryItemWriter<Employee> writer(EmployeeRepository repository) {
        final RepositoryItemWriter<Employee> repositoryItemWriter = new RepositoryItemWriter<>();
        repositoryItemWriter.setRepository(repository);
        repositoryItemWriter.setMethodName("save");
        return repositoryItemWriter;
    }
}
```

Even though the item writer code is executed no data is getting persisted to the **Employee** table on my local mysql database.
The application is able to connect to the database successfully and all the spring batch related tables are getting populated.

I was able to write the data to the **Employee** table if i use **JdbcBatchItemWriter** instead of **RepositoryItemWriter**:

```
    @Bean //WORKING
    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<Employee> writer(DataSource dataSource) {
    JdbcBatchItemWriter<Employee> itemWriter = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();

    itemWriter.setDataSource(dataSource);
    itemWriter.setSql("insert into Employee (firstName,lastName,age) values (:firstName,:lastName,:age)");
    itemWriter.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider());
    itemWriter.afterPropertiesSet();

    return itemWriter;
}
```

I am not including my **databaseconfiguration** class here.

What am i missing while using **RepositoryItemWriter** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess `EmployeeRepository` uses a JPA-based implementation. If this is the case, the cause of the issue would be that the `platformTransactionManager` injected on your step is of type `DataSourceTransactionManager` while it should be `JpaTransactionManager`.

Make sure you are using a `JpaTransactionManager` on your step and job repository when using `RepositoryItemWriter`.

Comment: Thanks @FadhelMahmoudBenHassine,
I used below code to fix my issue :
`
    @Override
    public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
      return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory.getObject());
    } 
    `